# Re-enabling Submit after prevent default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to unbind or reenable the prevent default so my form will submit on good data.

I have tried multiple examples.   Here is my code and some of the examples i tried.

This code works great for what i want to. Just the last thing and resetting the div which i can implement after i get this.

```
function lengthRestriction(elem, min, max) {
    var uInput = elem.value;
    if (uInput.length >= min && uInput.length <= max) {
        return true;
    } else {
        var cnt = document.getElementById('field');
        cnt.innerHTML = "Please enter between " + min + " and " + max + " characters";
        elem.focus();
        $('#ShoutTweet').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //bind('#ShoutTweet').submit();
            //$('#ShoutTweet').trigger('submit'); 
        });
    }
}​
```

i have a jsbin set up too http://jsbin.com/ebedab/93

Comment: You could try e.preventDefault() in the submit event of the form and self.submit() for the opposite effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking, but if your goal is to destroy your custom `submit` handler, then use this:

```
$("#ShoutTweet").unbind("submit");
```

This assumes that you have a normal (not Ajax) form.

Comment: wow it worked, i was putting the code in the wrong spot. Thank you ill accept it when the timer is off.

Comment: You are welcome. Did I guess correctly what you are trying to do? You wanted to disable your custom validation?

Comment: yes you did guess right. I am told I am not doing it properly : /

Answer (score 8):

Don't try to set up and cancel a submit handler from within your validation function, do it the other way around: call the validation from within a single submit handler, and only call `.preventDefault()` if the validation fails:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#ShoutTweet').submit(function(e) {
       if (/* do validations here, and if any of them fail... */) {
          e.preventDefault();
       }
    });

});
```

If all of your validations pass just don't call `e.preventDefault()` and the submit event will then happen by default.

Alternatively you can return `false` from your submit handler to prevent the default:

```
    $('#ShoutTweet').submit(function(e) {
       if (!someValidation())
          return false;

       if (!secondValidation())
          return false;

       if (someTestVariable != "somevalue")
          return false;

       // etc.
    });
```

Comment: You might want to review this before switching to using the return statement: [http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)  
  
In addition using preventDefault() would allow you to show all validation errors at once providing a cleaner user experience.

Comment: @lhoess - I agree that showing all validation errors at once is nicer (and that's what I do in my own projects), but I disagree that using return is a "mis-use" - if the effect you want is to exit from the handler immediately and you know bubbling doesn't matter (and for a submit from a form I usually don't care about bubbling) then it is fine. Of course you could compromise and go with `event.preventDefault(); return;` (without the `false`).

Comment: Just trying your first answer helped me, because the second with the return didn't, still thx

Answer (score 1):

Just call submit on the form

```
$('#ShoutTweet').submit();
```

Comment: That depends on what you intend to do - normally you would call it after the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

This works surely and enable form submission after `event.preventDefault();`

```
$('#your-login-form-id').on('submit', onSubmitLoader);

function onSubmitLoader(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.unbind('submit').submit(); // like if wants to enable form after 1s
    }, 1000)
}
```